# Python - input data into form and submit hidden form

Tags: javascript, python, html, form-submit, hidden-field

Ok so this is my **first post** on StackOverflow, so go easy on me. I'm literally stuck with my **Python** script. I looked all over the web, cannot find a solution!

So I used mechanize to login to a website (example: *http://www.foobar.com/*)

**HTML of form to login:**

`form id="loginForm" method="post" action="/z/0.123/?cmd=login-post" onsubmit="return someSubmitfunction();"`

**The form for the login of that website looks like this:**

```
    <HiddenControl(__FOO=someLongString) (readonly)>
    <TextControl(emailAddress=)>
    <PasswordControl(password=)>
    <CheckboxControl(persist=[*on])>
```

I WAS able to login to the website and redirect to an internal link (see further in code).

**Here is the code for the login...** Note: Request Method is a POST

```
    import urllib, urllib2
    import cookielib
    import mechanize

    # Note this is the FORM, but missing the HIDDEN value, LOOK lower in code
    EmailAddress = 'someusername'
    Password = 'somepassword'
    Persist = ['on',]

    browser = mechanize.Browser()

    # Enable cookie support
    cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar() 
    browser.set_cookiejar( cookiejar )

    # Browser options 
    browser.set_handle_equiv( True ) 
    browser.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
    browser.set_handle_referer( True ) 
    browser.set_handle_robots( False )

    # Pretend that I am a browser
    browser.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1 ) 
    browser.addheaders = [ ( 'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1' ) ]

    # Open webpage & add form fields
    browser.open('http://www.foobar.com/')
    browser.select_form(nr = 0) #select the ONLY form (Login form)
    browser.form['emailAddress'] = EmailAddress
    browser.form['password'] = Password
    browser.form['persist'] = Persist

    # Submit for FORM is an action, find it and redirect to internal page
    # Create new control & submit to internal page
    browser.new_control("HIDDEN", "action", {})
    control = browser.form.find_control("action")
    control.readonly = False
    browser["action"] = "/z/0.123/?cmd=login-post"
    browser.method = "post"
    browser.action = 'http://www.foobar.com/user/summary/'

    browser.submit()
```

**Alrighty, up to this point, I am fine.** I SUCCESSFULLY logged in and was redirected to *http://www.foobar.com/user/summary/* just like I wanted.

```
    url = browser.open('http://www.foobar.com/user/summary/')
    print url.read() # - see content of url HTML ### THIS WORKS ###
```

Now I use BeautifulSoup() to parse the HTML of /user/summary/ and successfully grab another form on this page. This form doesn't have an action, like the login form, but this is how it looks...

**I NEED HELP FROM HERE down.. I have trouble inputting my text(myInput) into the form and submitting!**

**HTML of form from .../user/summary/:**

`form method="post" id="foobar" name="foobar">`

**This is the submit button for the form:**

`onkeypress="return submitFormKey(event, '','foobar', 'foobar', 'pcm');">
img src="someuglyimage.jpg" class="submit" id="btn_Submit" onclick="submitForm('foobar', 'foobar', 'pcm');" alt="Foo"`

**This is the actual form: (THE ONLY FORM on this page, once again!)**

```
    <HiddenControl(hdnCmd=foobar) (readonly)>
    <TextControl(inputvalue=)>
```

I tried many methods of submitting. I tried using Selenium, Splinter, urlib(1 & 2), and even JSON, javascript, iframe, embed, etc. **I'M STUCK, HELP PLZ!**

**I thought this will work, i tried with and without Hidden control:**

```
    browser.select_form(nr = 0) #select the 1st form for inputting value
    browser.form['inputvalue'] = myInput #MY INPUT I WANT THERE

    browser.new_control("hidden", "foobar", {})
    control = browser.form.find_control("foobar")
    control.readonly = False
    #browser["foobar"] = "/?cmd=foobar&from=/user/summary"
    browser.method = "post"
    response = browser.submit()
    print response.read()
```

**MY RESULTS:**

Apparently It seems to redirect me to the homepage of the website (302 Redirect). So I KNOW that most likely it's something to do with the hidden value and passing it to the javascript/Ajax call (onclick="submitForm) when I submit. I read about CSRF tokens and it could be that, but if anyone has any ideas on how to do this, let me know because I'm in desperate need of help.

And somehow I cannot find the form of .../user/summary/ (console tells me this) because I am redirected to the homepage, even though I dont submit the browser, until after I input all the form fields...

I can read the HTML of .../user/summary/ and find the "foobar" form! This is why I am so confused. I can read it, parse it, but when i try to input myInput into the form, somehow I get redirected to homepage, but I am still logged in!

THANKS pplz.. hopefully I was clear!